# how to find the last element in a foreach?

Tags: php

This is what I am trying, using [SimpleHtmlDom library](https://github.com/PeratX/SimpleHtmlDom/wiki/PHP-Simple-HTML-DOM-Parser-Manual)

```
  foreach($html->find('div[class="blogcontent]') as $a) {
    foreach($a->find('p') as $elm) {
      echo $elm->href .$elm->plaintext. '<p>';
      if($elm, -1) {
       return;
      }
    }
  }
```

I am trying to implement what their doc say:

> ```
> > // Find lastest anchor, returns element object or null if not found
> > (zero based) $ret = $html->find('a', -1);
> ```

But I get:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ','

I need to stop the loop and don't echo the last `p` that it finds

Comment: What is `if($a, -1) {` supposed to do?

Comment: I don't understand what you intend to do however, please reformulate an give an example. You don't want to have a '<p>' at the end of the loop ? Don't echo at each loop iteration, store text in a string, and a the end of the loop, remove last 3 characters and echo the string. That's what I doing in cases like that. You could also create an array of values for each iteration, and at the end of the loop implode the array with <p> as glue

Comment: @MarkBaker udated the question with a clearer explanation

Comment: @Pierre updated the question

Answer (score 1):

**Alternative 1:**

You could try to get the last element in the "old way" which is to use **count()** to get the number of elements then with a counter compare if it is in the **last element** then if it's true you skipt the **last element**. This way you can do it:

```
$a=$html->find('div[class="blogcontent]';
$i = 0;

foreach($a as $as) {
    $b=$as->find('p');
    $total_items = count($b);
    foreach($b as $elm) {
       if ($i == $total_items - 1) {
          return; // or you can use break function to see if it stops on the last element
       }
       echo $elm->href .$elm->plaintext. '<p>';

    }
  }
```

**Alternative 2:**

You could use **end()** to know if you are on the last element  this way:

```
$a=$html->find('div[class="blogcontent]';

foreach($a as $as) {
    $b=$as->find('p');

    foreach($b as $elm) {
       if ($elm === end($b)) {
          return; // or you can use break function to see if it stops on the last element
       }
       echo $elm->href .$elm->plaintext. '<p>';

    }
  }
```

Comment: i still get the last p tag

Comment: it's weird because end() is used specially capture the last element of a foreach() loop

Comment: Code dumps do not make for good answers. You should explain *how* and *why* this solves their problem. I recommend reading, "[How do I write a good answer?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Thank you @JohnConde I will explain it.

Comment: Thank you @JohnConde. I have updated my answer. Have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove the last tag then rather than iterate over all of the data, fetch all values from `find()` and then remove the last one with `array_pop()`...

```
  foreach($html->find('div[class="blogcontent"]') as $a) {
    $pTags = array_pop($a->find('p'));
    foreach( $pTags as $elm) {
      echo $elm->href .$elm->plaintext. '<p>';
    }
  }
```

If you just want the last `<p>` tag then

```
$pTags = $a->find('p');
$lastTag = $pTags[count($pTags)-1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to identify the last entry, it might be easier to display the `<p>` before each entry except for the first

```
foreach($a->find('p') as $key => $elm) {
    if ($key > 0) {
       echo '<p>';
    }
    echo $elm->href .$elm->plaintext;
}
```